# deal with deep nested json in swift decodable

Tags: json, swift

I have this deep nested JSON:

```
{
"response": {
    "status": {
        "status_code": 200,
        "execute_time": 0.0068638324737549
    },
    "list": {
        "beers": [
            {
                "beer": {
                    "id": 323,
                    "name": "Saint Arnold",
                    "style": "IPA"
                }
            },
            {
                "beer": {
                    "id": 873,
                    "name": "Black Angel",
                    "style": "Stout"
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
}
```

I would like to create just a struct like:

```
struct Beer {
  let id: Int
  let name: String
  let style: String

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    ... custom decode ...
  }
}
```

and make a custom decode to decode from json just to this model and not to create a struct for every level of the json.

I don't know where to start, someone could help?

I tried to play with `container.encode()` but I can't understand how it's work in my case.

Comment: You just want one of the beers or all of the beers? If you want all the beers your current `Beer` type won't work since it only represents one beer. But in any case, Just write the nested structs. You'll have a much easier time than writing the decoding code. You don't need to include the properties that you don't need, just make a similar structure.

Comment: I would +1 the notion of making structs over every layer here. Though the value of the "list" key can be `Dictionary<String, ListableThing>` (this is named poorly. "lists" is a dictionary, not a list/array), and the value for the "beers" key can be just an `Array<Beer>`.  The "list" and "beers" keys seem redundant here. Do you control this JSON?

Comment: @Sweeper I want all beers decoding with JSONDecoder().decode([Beer].self, for: data)

Comment: @Alexander nope, the json arrive from a service that is not under my control. I know that is not easy but I would like to do it in this way to keep everything outside clean.

Comment: Well then you must at least have one more type than `Beer`, because you can't control how an array of beers is decoded with only `Beer`.